# How do I set LinkButton Visible Property from content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do i set the visible property of a Link button inside update panel inside master page from a content page.

This I have done inside a click event of command button without luck

```
      dim showLnk as Linkbutton   =ctype(master.findcontrol("updatepanel1").findcontrol("lnkLogOut",LinkButton)
showLnk.visible =true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this code inside the Master page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="parentPanel">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogOut" runat="server">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

To set the visibility from a content page simply do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim showLnk As LinkButton = Master.FindControl("lnkLogOut")
    showLnk.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: the code I posted and the one  you did run without error but the prob is the link button visibility still remains the same, i am suspecting something is overriding the setting

Comment: Well in that case something is probably overriding it.Do a search through your solution and find out what it is